# Extend @objc protocol with Comparable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, comparable

I am trying to extend my protocol `Option` with `Comparable` to use simple `.sort()` method.

Below short example only with `Equatable` to show errors.

```
@objc protocol Option: Equatable {
    var title: String { get }
    var enabled: Bool { get }
    var position: Int { get }
}

func ==(lhs: Option, rhs: Option) -> Bool {
    return lhs.position == rhs.position
}
```

The `Option` protocol must be marked as `@objc` or inherit from `NSObjectProtocol` because it will be used with `UIKit`.

Errors:

1. > @objc protocol 'Option' cannot refine non-@objc protocol
   >   'Equatable'
2. > Protocol 'Option' can only be used as a generic constraint
   >   because it has Self or associated type requirements

Do you have any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: maybe u need to use `dynamic` decleration for your variable to use it with `objc`

Comment: I don't see `SelectOption` in your code

Comment: @Cristik thanks for correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Equatable` lives in the Swift world only, thus you cannot extend it to a protocol that will be used by Objective-C. Trying to do this results in error #1

Protocols that have a `Self` requirement (i.e. at least one method from the protocol declaration contains `Self`) cannot be used as arguments to functions, or to variable declarations, only as arguments to a generic clause, e.g. `func doSomething<T: Option>(argument: T)`.

Removing `Equatable` from the `Option` protocol declaration, and declaring `==` as generic on `Option` will solve the compile errors. As for sorting, you can also overload the `<` operator, and sort via that operator (without needing to implement `Comparable`):

```
@objc protocol Option {
    var title: String { get }
    var enabled: Bool { get }
    var position: Int { get }
}

func ==<T: Option>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.position == rhs.position
}

func <<T: Option>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.position < rhs.position
}
```

This allows you to pass objects that conform to the protocol to `UIKit`, and to also compare them within your swift code.

```
class A: NSObject, Option { .. }
class B: NSObject, Option { ... }

let a = A()
let b = B()
a == b  // compiles, and returns true if a and b have the same position
let c: [Option] = [a, b]
c.sort(<) // returns a sorted array by the `position` field
```

One important note regarding the sorting code above: if you don't specify the type for `c`, then the compiler infers its type as `[NSObject]`, and the `sort` call will not compile due to ambiguity of the `<` operator. You need to explicitly declare `c` as `[Option]` to take advantage of the overloaded operator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is half the battle :) If I want use .sort() on collection of elements (Element: Option) I need mark protocol as Comparable. I have tried @nonobjc declaration on extension but i doesn't work..

Comment: @dtd check the updated answer, it also addresses the sorting

Comment: @Critic If there is impossible inherit from `Comparable` protocol, your solution if very nice, and I will use it. I didn't know that I can use just comperation operator `c.sort(<)`. I also add simple extension for Array: `extension Array where Element: Option { func sort() -> [Element] { return self.sort(<) } }`

Comment: @dtd `<` is actually a function (just like any other operator), this is why you can pass it to `sort()`. If you don't believe, just Cmd+Click on `<` Xcode will take you to its definition :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue can be fixed by the new protocol oriented programming features introduced in swift 2.0

> @objc protocol 'Option' cannot refine non-@objc protocol 'Equatable'

As the error states, the `Equatable` protocol is a swift protocol that you can't to Obj C context

> Protocol 'Option' can only be used as a generic constraint because it
>   has Self or associated type requirements

You can achieve this in the following way:

```
@objc protocol Option {
    var title: String { get }
    var enabled: Bool { get }
    var position: Int { get }
}

extension Equatable where Self : Option
{

}

extension Comparable where Self : Option
{

}

func ==(lhs: Option, rhs: Option) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.position == rhs.position
}

func <(lhs: Option, rhs: Option) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.position < rhs.position
}

func >(lhs: Option, rhs: Option) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.position > rhs.position
}
```

And your class and implementation looks like:

```
class MyClass: Option
{
    @objc var title: String = ""
    @objc var enabled: Bool = true
    @objc var position: Int = 0

    init()
    {
    }

    convenience init(title : String, enabled : Bool, position: Int)
    {
        self.init()
        self.title    = title
        self.enabled  = enabled
        self.position = position
    }
}

let firstObj               = MyClass()
let secondObj              = MyClass()
let optionArray : [Option] = [firstObj, secondObj]

// Sort array of options
optionArray.sort(<)
```